# Any ways to Automatically Export or Sync from Outlook Calendar?

Tags: calendar, synchronization, outlook

I am wondering if anyone knows of any program, or other solution on the market right now that I can use to automatically extract data from Outlook calendar events from multiple users to a single place. I have tried Robin's Meeting Room scheduling system, but that requires that I use either an Exchange Service Account, or a Global Admin login (both of which are unavailable to me).

Instead, what I would prefer is if any user can use as few steps as possible to connect their Outlook calendars to somewhere that would manage to automatically sync from Outlook.

Please let me know if anyone knows of any solution that would make this possible, or if I would just have to make my own application using Microsoft Outlook Calendar's API's. Thanks!